# Make function access outside variables in PHP

Tags: php, function, loops, variables

I have a function with an array that has a lot of variables inside it that are declared outside of the function.

Here is a stripped down version of the function:

```
function get_badges(){
    $badge_array = array(

        array(
            "Comment Freak",
            ($user_revision >= $revision_master_req) && ($tixx1 >= $tixx2)
        ),

        array(
            "Revision Freak",
            ($user_revisionx55 >= $revision_master_reqx134) && ($tixx11233 >= $tixx1342)
        )

    );

    return $badge_array;
}
```

My question is, what would be the best way to access variables outside the function when considering performance? Upon research, I read I need to use `globals` but apparently that is not a good approach, particularly if I have many variables...

Comment: passing them as a parameter?

Comment: Pass the variables as function arguments. e.g. `function get_badges($user_revision, $revision_master_req....)` You may also consider grouping data into class objects or arrays, and passing just a few arguments instead.

Comment: @lolka_bolka How does this work?

Comment: @Populus Can you please write up an answer detailing exactly how this works? Please consider I am learning PHP so a lot of terms are completely new to me.

Comment: Function parameters in PHP work just like in all other programming languages.

Comment: You should avoid using global variables if you can. Pass your variables into your function as parameters. That said, this doesn't look like a good use of a function. Wouldn't it be easier just to do this inline?

Comment: @Populus Oh right right! Now I get this. Feel free to write an answer and I will accept it as correct.

Comment: Tell us exactly which variables you want to access, and we will provide you an example of a snippet using them.

Comment: @Zeratops No it is fine, I understand the concept of parameters now. How could I have forgot :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your variables as parameters, example:

```
function get_badges($user_revision, $revision_master_req, etc... ){
    $badge_array = array(

        array(
            "Comment Freak",
            ($user_revision >= $revision_master_req) && ($tixx1 >= $tixx2)
        ),

        array(
            "Revision Freak",
            ($user_revisionx55 >= $revision_master_reqx134) && ($tixx11233 >= $tixx1342)
        )

    );

    return $badge_array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass params as an array. And also, you can create a little helper function what is build this array for you, so you do not need to build it every time. Global is not so good, but this time it will help you.

```
$args = getBagesArgs();
$bagets = get_badges($args);

function get_badges($args) {
    $badge_array = array(
        array(
            "Comment Freak",
            ($args['user_revision'] >= $args['revision_master_req']) && ($args['tixx1'] >= $$args['tixx2'])
        ),
        array(
            "Revision Freak",
            ($args['user_revisionx55'] >= $args['revision_master_reqx134']) && ($args['tixx11233'] >= $args['tixx1342'])
        )
    );
    return $badge_array;
}

function getBagesArgs() {
    global $user_revision, $revision_master_req, $tixx1, $tixx2, $user_revisionx55, $revision_master_reqx134, $tixx11233, $tixx1342;
    $args = array(
        'user_revision' => $user_revision,
        'revision_master_req' => $revision_master_req,
        'tixx1' => $tixx1,
        'tixx2' => $tixx2,
        'user_revisionx55' => $user_revisionx55,
        'revision_master_reqx134' => $revision_master_reqx134,
        'tixx11233' => $tixx11233,
        'tixx1342' => $tixx1342
    );
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The calling

```
get_badges( array( 'user_revision ' => 4211
    , 'revision_master_req' => 9845
    , 'tixx1 ' => 778, 
) );
```

The body :

```
function get_badges($all_vars=array()){
$badge_array = array(

    array(
        "Comment Freak",
        ($all_vars['user_revision'] >= $all_vars['revision_master_req']) && ($all_vars['tixx1 ']>= $all_vars['tixx2'])
    ),

etc...
);
return $badge_array;
}
```